# Why can't I access a single element in Dataframe in Pandas using only brackets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax

I understand both of the following ways are allowed:

1. to access a single column: `df['rowA']`
2. to access a few rows: `df[3:5]`

But `df[3:5, 'rowA']`, or `df[7, 9]`, gives an exception (`TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`). What's the rationale behind that?

Comment: When dealing with numbers, it is difficult because, the interpreter has to infer whether you want is 1 as the index position or if your columns are labeled as 0,1,2,3, do you want column label 1.  That is why the most safe thing to use are the .loc and .iloc selectors.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of .loc and .iloc so I guess it's mostly to avoid ambiguity then? But if we have both indices as strings then it's clear that they are by label: for example `df[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]`. It seems that python should at least allow this syntax. For the mixed indexing, it could also default on indices first and then on string, for example. I just don't understand why they wanna ban this notation entirely `df[indices, indices]`

Answer (score 1):

instead of `df[3:5, 'rowA']` use:

```
df.loc[df.index[3:5], 'rowA']
```

instead of `df[7, 9]` use:

```
df.iloc[[7,9]]
```

Please read [official Pandas docs about indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can chain them too, a combo of getting column and slice. The order is irrelevant.

```
df['rowA'][3:5]
```

Or:

```
df[3:5]['rowA']
```